# Python xml.etree.ElementTree Parsing Forward Slashes

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm trying to parse XML returned by the Stanford CoreNLP in python using the xml.etree.ElementTree module, but I seem to keep running into this error.

Here is the error I get:

```
File "my_script.py", line 5
    root = ET.fromstring(content)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 4473, column 19
```

I checked out out what's on line 4473 in the XML file:

```
<word>5 1/2</word>
```

Column 19 starts at the `5`.

I assume the problem is due to the forward slash in the number `5 1/2` since this is the first instance the `5 1/2` occurs in the XML file. Does anyone know a way I can still parse the XML file with the forward-slashes?

Here is the code also:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
f = open("samplefiles/samplefile999.txt.xml","r");
content = f.read()
f.close();
root = ET.fromstring(content)
```

Comment: I think your issue is somewhere else in your xml file.  If I use a simple XML file like this `<something><word>5 1/2</word></something>`, your code works fine.  If my XML is like this `<something<word>5 1/2</word></something>`, I get a similar error to what you're getting. Perhaps running your XML through a validator may help determine the issue.

Comment: Yes, the issue must be something else. Having a forward slash in the content of an XML element is perfectly fine.

Comment: I found out that the problem was the space character between the 5 and 1 was a NO-BREAK SPACE character (\u00a0) rather than a space character (\u0020). I was also reading the xml string in an encoding called ISO-8859-2 (<-- usually this is 1) rather than UTF-8.